# MySQL count all outside limit

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL query which counts hours we have worked from the top five of our clients. This works fine, and I am plotting the data on a graph. What I am trying to achieve is a calculation within the query that returns a sixth result set which is the sum of all the hours which are not in the top five. i.e. An 'Other' result, so that the sum of all 6 results would equal the total of sum of projects.hours.

My query:

```
SELECT
  SUM(projects.hours) AS total_hours
FROM projects
GROUP BY projects.companyID
ORDER BY total_hours DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT
SUM(projects.hours) AS total_hours,
(SELECT SUM(projects.hours) FROM projects) AS all_hours
FROM 
projects
GROUP BY 
projects.companyID
ORDER BY total_hours DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Subtract total_hours from all_hours in your application.

Comment: +1 for the simple and direct approach. To make it slightly less simple and direct, you could assign `total_hours` and `all_hours` to user-defined variables, and perform the subtraction in the SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  1 no,
  projects.company,
  SUM(projects.hours) AS total_hours
FROM 
  projects
GROUP BY 
  projects.companyID
ORDER BY
  total_hours DESC
LIMIT 5

UNION ALL

SELECT
  2 no,
  'Others',
  SUM(projects.hours) AS total_hours
FROM 
  projects
WHERE projects.companyID NOT IN 
( SELECT companyID 
  FROM 
  (  SELECT
      projects.companyID
    FROM 
      projects
    GROUP BY 
      projects.companyID
    ORDER BY
      SUM(total_hours) DESC
    LIMIT 5
  ) AS tmp
)
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you. Just a quick question, what do the '1 no' and '2 no' bits do?

Comment: @Joseph, If allows you to know which rows come from the first and which rows from the second part of the query.

Comment: @Johan, Also one little extra thing. I also SELECT projects.company_name for each of the ones in the first 5. How would I set this to be 'Other' for the second query?

Comment: Also, I have just tried to run this and get this error: "This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'". Upgrading the MySQL isn't an option. I am running version 5.0.32

Comment: @Joseph, use Dan's code instead, this code is needlessly complicated (`union`), slow (`IN (select ..`) and does not work on any version of MySQL.

Comment: @Johan: It can work with the edit now. It could be slow because of the `IN` though, you are right.

Comment: @Joseph, alternatively you can change the second part to: `SELECT 2 no, SUM(projects.hours) AS total_hours FROM  projects   GROUP BY    projects.companyID   ORDER BY SUM(total_hours) DESC   LIMIT 5,9999999`, But Dan's code is still better.

Answer (score 0):

How about a combination of both approaches, with the addition of a rollup we can remove the need for the IN

(I'm not sure if you can `rollup` with a `limit` though, I don't have MYSQL here so can't test, sorry)

NOTE: I would expect this to return a company id of NULL that contains the total number of other rows,

```
SELECT companyID, 
CASE WHEN companyID IS NULL THEN 
    sum(Total_hours)
ELSE
    sum(Total_hours) * -1
END

FROM 
(           
    SELECT companyID,SUM(projects.hours) AS total_hours,  
    FROM  projects 
    GROUP BY  projects.companyID 
    ORDER BY total_hours DESC WITH ROLLUP LIMIT 5 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT null,SUM(projects.hours)*-1 total_hours FROM projects  
)
GROUP BY companyID
```