# how to select table with limit and return the outside limit into record named 'other' with MYSQL

Tags: mysql, limit

I have data like this:

```
Team | goal
a    | 5
b    | 8
a    | 5
f    | 8
c    | 5
a    | 3
g    | 5
d    | 8
a    | 5
e    | 4
a    | 9
a    | 8
b    | 2
c    | 3
f    | 1
```

I want to make select table to be like this: 
example:

```
Team   | sum(goal)
a      |  14
b      |  13
c      |  12
d      |  11
others | sum(outside limit 0,4)
```

So I want to list top 4 team with his total goal

and also return all outside limit into one record named 'others' (sum the goal from other team outside top 4)

a,b,c,d is not defined yet, use `select , order, and limit to get TOP 4 Goal`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two queries joined by a union will give the desired result:

```
( SELECT team AS team,SUM(goal) AS goals 
  FROM table
  GROUP BY 1 
  LIMIT 4 )
UNION
( SELECT 'Other',SUM(other.goals) FROM 
  ( SELECT team AS team,SUM(goal) AS goals 
    FROM table 
    GROUP BY 1 
    LIMIT 5,999999 ) other
)
```

Comment: Ya, i have found the answer, and it match with yours, so i choose this answer, although, my answer is based on @Ankit explanation..
Thank You..

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you meant by "outside limit 0,4". But you can do with `Union` query:

Like below:

```
select Team,sum(goal) as goal  from table where Team in('a','b','c','d') group by  Team 
union
select 'Others' as Team ,sum(goal) as goal  table  where Team not in('a','b','c','d') 
group by  1
```

Comment: Hello @KingFisher, thanks for the quick answer, but "a,b,c,d is not defined yet, use select , order, and limit to get TOP 4 Goal" , can you help me?

Comment: you can use subquery  and join like :select s1.team,sum(s1.goal) as goal  from table as s1 join (select team from table limit 0,4) as s2  on s1.team=s2.team  group by  team

Comment: Hi @KingFisher, outside limit 0,4 is outside the top 4, so i want to list top 4 team with his total goal, and sum the goal from other team outside top 4, sound like easy yea... :D

Answer (score 0):

For selecting top 4 teams query will be like this:-

```
select `Team`, sum(`goal`) as goals  
from table_name 
order by goals desc limit 4;
```

For teams other then top $ query will be like this

```
select `Team`, sum(`goal`) as goals  
from table_name 
order by goals desc limit 4,10;
```

(I did not know your total no of teams so I took 10 as a reference)

Comment: thank you @Ankit, but thats is the problem, we can't total number of team... i have tried http://stackoverflow.com/a/6690599 but my MySQL doesn't support LIMIT in SubQuery

Comment: but in my example there is no sub query,have you tried this code?

Comment: yes your code is right, but to select outside the limit, and we don't know the number of team yet, we have to use subquery..... so the problem is list the outside limit, without knowing the total team. click the link http://stackoverflow.com/a/6690599

Comment: by the way you can count the no of ditinct teams seperately if sub query is not supporting for you through count(distinct team). othervise take outer limit maximum like 100 or 1000 because it doesnot affect performance.